# Ziparchive, addfromstring, skip line (php)

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I use Ziparchive class to add textfile to my zip.

The text file is succeffly added but **I can't skip lines with \n**

```
$Zip->addFromString("Readme.txt", "Please visit \n For help center");
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? How did you verify it? Make a hexeditor screenshot of the resulting file.

Comment: How I verify it : I opened the zip file, opened the readme.txt and there is no skip line

Comment: It's just a part of my script

Comment: So, asking for guesses then? Use a better editor. Or platform-specific CRLF instead of just a newline.

Comment: I think you didn't get what I want to do <?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'file content goes here');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>

Comment: I want fo example to write "file content" in first line and "goes hre" in the second line

Answer (score 1):

Solved with \r\n instead of \n

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is old but I ran into the same problem today)

If you want to view the file with notepad you need to use \r\n instead of \n. BUT you shouldn't. It will produce problems on mac and linux. Just use Notepad++ or any other Texteditor. \n will work

And maybe use the term "linebreak" for \n instead "skip lines"